# simple example for Transition to Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I currently use [Container Registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/xyzproject?project=xyzproject) and builds images with command line like an example given below

```
./mvnw com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build -Dimage=gcr.io/xyzproject/myimage
```

Container Registry page asks to **Transition to [Artifact Registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts) **

> Artifact Registry is the recommended service for managing container
> images. Container Registry is still supported but will only receive
> critical security fixes. Learn more about options to transition to
> Artifact Registry.

I enabled the Artifact Registry, but could not find an example as simple as issuing a command like
**./mvnw compile jib:build**
to make the artifact that I can use in [Google Cloud Run](https://console.cloud.google.com/run?project=xyzproject)

If anyone has simple document to build and deploy spring boot app using Artifact Registry to Google Cloud Run, please update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this [document](https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/getting-started-with-artifact-registry-deploying-to-cloud-run-7aa9f2c65d07) created by `Jen Person` he has outlined in an easily understandable way for playing with Cloud run and artifact registry. He started from creating your code to building an application image, uploading it to artifact registry and finally deploying on cloud run. There is an official git repository on the same from google [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/981bf0a6c21e674f78de25877302dce38de4fc6c/run) you can find multiple java examples for cloud run.

Comment: @puzzled is your issue resolved..? revert back if you are still facing some challenges..